# How to define a header parameter with multiple attributes in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

I need to define a header parameter like this `X-Custom: id1=uuid1;id2=uuid3`

Since this is a common header for all paths I want to define it once and reference it every time. So far I came up with this:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3

components:
  parameters:
    customHeader:
      name: "X-Custom"
      in: header           # <--- produces error
      required: true
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          id1:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          id2:
            type: string
            format: uuid
      style: matrix
      explode: true
```

But I get an error that 'header' is not allowed and the parameter does not show up in the preview.
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Do you use `openapi: 3.x.x` or `swagger: '2.0'`? Your definition looks correct except for `style: matrix` - header parameters [support](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#header) `style: simple` only.

Comment: openapi version added. Ok, I'll go for `style: simple` for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAPI 3 [supports](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#header) only `style: simple` for header parameters. This means that objects can be serialized in one of two ways:

```
# {"id1": "uuid1", "id2": "uuid2"} becomes...

# explode: false
X-Custom: id1,uuid1,id2,uuid2

# explode: true
X-Custom: id1=uuid1,id2=uuid2
```

Note that none of these styles match your expected format `X-Custom: id1=uuid1;id2=uuid2` with `;` as a separator. In fact, OpenAPI currently does not have a way to define `;`-separated header values.

The most you can do is define the entire header as a string, mention the header value format in the `description`, and provide an `example` value:

```yaml
    customHeader:
      name: X-Custom
      in: header
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      example: id1=uuid1;id2=uuid2
```

There are existing feature requests to improve header serialization styles in OpenAPI:

- [Support for structured-headers de/serialization](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1980)
- [Make it easier to define link headers](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/667)

If you are designing a new API rather than documenting an existing one, another workaround is to split the header into two headers:

```
X-id1: uuid1
X-id2: uuid2
```